# Run multiple function onClick jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have the following case:

```
fun MyScreen(
onNavigateUp: () -> Unit,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
viewModel: MyViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    Scaffold(
         topBar = {
           ...
            , actions = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = onNavigateUp
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Done,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(id = ...)
                )
            }
        })
    },
)
```

I would like to do something like:

```
onClick = {viewModel.doSomething(),onNavigateUp}
```

So basically call a view model function and then navigate back.
But when I do that the IDE tells me that `onNavigateUp` is unused.
Is there any good practice in jetpack compose on how to execute multiple functions/lambdas upon an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
onClick = {
     viewModel.doSomething()
     onNavigateUp() // or onNavigateUp.invoke()
}
```

Comment: Damn, so I just had to add the parentheses.

Comment: Important thing here is parentheses in function name